# Java Runtime.exec run slower and slower

Tags: java, time, runtime, exec

The Java Runtime.exec run slower and slower when run the other command .

I timed the "Runtime.getRuntime().exec" about three days , and this function cost more and more time ,it from 0/1 ms to 500+ ms. so ...

but when I run the "ipmitool raw 0x3e 0x31 3 1" in shell script, the time cost is normally.

so who knows what's reason for this problem ? Thanks.

This is the code :

```
 String shStr="ipmitool raw 0x3e 0x31 3 1";
 public static List<String> runShell(String shStr) throws Exception {
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();

        long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Process process;
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/bin/sh","-c",shStr},null,null);

        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("runShell exec time cost" + (time1 - start_time));

    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(process
            .getInputStream());
    InputStreamReader stderrReader = new 
    InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream());

    LineNumberReader input = new LineNumberReader(ir);
    LineNumberReader errInput = new LineNumberReader(stderrReader);

    String line;
    process.waitFor();

    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        strList.add(line);
    }
    System.out.println("ERROR");
    while ((line = errInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }


    return strList;
}
```

Comment: are the processes terminating correctly?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes , it is terminated correctly. This function is used in a while loop .

Comment: what are you doing with the result `strList`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I split the "strList " and saved it to a List. and then use the list to do some other things. and You mean the strList String may affect the "Runtime.getRuntime().exec" ?

Comment: If the `List` is just growing, then lack of memory may slow things down

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks Scary Wombat, I found memory is enough ,and the List is not just growing . and the function - "Runtime.getRuntime().exec" is to create a child progress, whether it is reflected by other progress? I am puzzled .

Comment: @ScaryWombat I test it just now , it is normal when I run this function in a while loop and do nothing after it , just sleep 1 s, but , when I run some calculate logic(10%) after it ,  This will affect the function's performance step by step .